# PHP PDO MSSQL select memo type (on ubuntu server 12.04)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a bit of a question that i cant seem to find the answer anywhere.

Reasonably simple, im doing a select statement from a table in a database. Its a simple query, but im not getting any results when i select a field that is of type "memo"

this is my code, but im cetain that there is no sytax errors.

```
$STH6 = $DBH->query("SELECT CStr(dbo.tblRemarks.Description) AS Rmks 
FROM dbo_tblRemarks 
WHERE dbo.tblRemarks.RemarkLinkID = '$RemarkLinkID';");


$STH6->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

while($row6 = $STH6->fetch()){

$Description = $row6->Rmks;

}


echo "<td>" . $Description .  "</td> ";
echo $NewLine;
```

If anyone has experience with "memo" type, please let me know how i should pull the data out of the database.

Comment: You can refer this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=6572

Comment: That bug was submitted 13 years ago. Are you sure it's still valid?

Comment: That bug has been closed,  already checked.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar that answer is unfortunatly for php running on a windows server, i should clarify that this is a ubuntu box.

Comment: SQL Server has a `memo` datatype ?